# Скачивание страниц с помощью libcurl и curb

Tags: curl, ruby

Хочу скачать несколько страниц товаров с сайта, но `curl` не передаёт параметр, и поэтому вместо того, что б качать:

```
https://www.petsаnic.com/snacks-huesos-para-perros/?p=1
https://www.petsаnic.com/snacks-huesos-para-perros/?p=2
https://www.petsаnic.com/snacks-huesos-para-perros/?p=3
https://www.petsаnic.com/snacks-huesos-para-perros/?p=4
```

Оно качает:

```
https://www.petsаnic.com/snacks-huesos-para-perros/
https://www.petsаnic.com/snacks-huesos-para-perros/
https://www.petsаnic.com/snacks-huesos-para-perros/
https://www.petsаnic.com/snacks-huesos-para-perros/
```

Соответственно код:

```ruby
CATEGORY = "https://www.petsonic.com/snacks-huesos-para-perros"
category_url = "#{CATEGORY}/?p=#{page_number}"
category_page = Curl.get(category_url)
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте передать запрос хеш-таблицей:

```ruby
category_page =
  Curl.get("https://www.petsonic.com/snacks-huesos-para-perros/", { "p" => page_number })
```

Comment: Не помогло результат тот же(

Comment: @ФедяЦябук  Вы уверены?  Только что попробовал на своём локальном сервере, запрос передаётся с `?p=1`.

Comment: И ещё, вы уверены, что информация на этой странице содержится в _HTML,_ а не подгружается отдельным *AJAX*-запросом?

Comment: Не уверен, а что делать в этом случае?

Comment: @ФедяЦябук  Если у ресурса есть руководство по _API,_ читать его.  Если нет — реверсить их _API_ самостоятельно, смотря, какие запросы идут с клиента в Консоли разработчика вашего браузера.

Comment: Всё равно не передаётся как надо(

Comment: Может я вам код кину, вы глянете?

Comment: Лучше добавьте в вопрос.  Возможно, кто-то ещё вам подскажет.

Comment: но у вас код который вы мне скинули корректно работает?

Comment: Мой код должен корректно посылать запрос с `?p=1`.  Аналогичный код, направленный на мой сервер, делает именно это.  Ещё раз, если содержимое страницы подгружается скриптами, то вы не в ту сторону копаете.  Извините, но больше времени у меня нет.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо за ответы